# Android Chrome table border issue

Tags: android, google-chrome, border

I've a problem with border render on Android Chrome browser. You can see yellow hairline borders between cells. But borders in CSS are sets to zero.

This render issue is only on Android Chrome browser, desktop Chrome render is borderless.

How it looks on Android Chrome browser Nexus 7 (2012), Android 5.0, Chrome 39.0.2171.59

[image]

It is possible to fix this by some css or js workaround?

Here is the [jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/gxv3g532/2/)

```
<style>
.bg {
    background-color: #FFD906;
    padding: 10px;
}
.demo {
        width:100%;
        border:0px solid;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        padding:5px;
    }
    .demo td {
        border:0px solid;
        text-align:center;
        padding:5px;
        background:#000;
        color: #FFF;
    }
</style>

    <div class="bg">
<table class="demo">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell 1</td>
        <td>Cell 2</td>
        <td>Cell 3</td>
        <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I jut had the same issue. And you're right, it looks like the problem occurs in the rendering engine of Android Chrome Browser.

Chrome Browser just ignores it:

```css
border: 0px;
```

In order to solve it, you have to define a 1px border of the same color as the background of the table-cell. In my example I applied:

```css
border: 1px solid #fff; /* Google Chrome Mobile Fix */
```

And as mentioned, the background of the table-cell was #fff, too.

I hope this helps!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove the solid in border.

```
.demo td {
     border:0px;
     text-align:center;
     padding:5px;
     background:#000;
     color: #FFF;
}
```

and if it really does not work.

```
.demo td {
    border:1px solid #000;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    background:#000;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Tim, thanks for your suggestions but it is still the same (desktop browser fine, Chrome mobile not. It must be a render issue

Answer (score 0):

[image]

To complete answer of @Chris

In the above photo, we have a **TR tag** and we have 5 **TD tags** in it

**1) Free of data**

**2) Contains (Yes)**

**3) Free of data**

**4) Contains (No)**

**5) Free of data**

in the most android web browsers you'll see this terrible result

It's not just in Android Chrome!

In my opinion 70% of mobile browsers shows this result

**How to resolve it?**

It's so easy

**Wrong Way:**

```
border-top:4px solid #1B4B8D;
```

**Right Way:**

```
border-top:4px solid #1B4B8D;
border-left:1px solid #1B4B8D;
border-right:1px solid #1B4B8D;
border-bottom:1px solid #1B4B8D;
```

**Short Answer:**

If you set a **border-x** property to a **TD**

You must use all other **border-x** properties in it too, even with 1px.

All.... all of them together. not just 1 of them...

(To Test) Open Chrome > Open your website using wampserver or IIS > Right Click > Click Inspect > Click Mobile Icon > Choose your mobile device > and watch the result in any mobile very fast and easy

**Edit:**

and also this part of code can do miracle:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

add it on top of your css file or add it as style in your table tag